# Why can't I check for a constraints on a type using requires?

Tags: c++, c++20

I'm trying to understand how to use Concepts to do interface checks on a type (duck typing?), and produce the most readable code. I have the following `concept`:

```
template <typename T>
concept Shape = requires(const T& t)
{
    { t.area() } -> std::convertible_to<float>;
};
```

And then use it as follows

```
template <typename T>
struct shape_checker_check_in_ctor 
{
    shape_checker_check_in_ctor()
    {static_assert(Shape<T>);}
};

struct Circle : shape_checker_check_in_ctor<Circle>
{
    float r;
    float area() const 
    {return 22*r*r/7;}
};
```

Which works fine, but I think having the `static_assert` in the constructor of the constraint checker makes its role a tad less obvious. What I'd like instead is the following, which involves less boilerplate:

```
template <typename T> requires Shape<T>
struct shape_checker_with_constraint 
{};
```

And then

```
struct Square : shape_checker_with_constraint<Square>
{
    double side;
    float area() const 
    {return side*side;}
};
```

But it doesn't work. Full code here: https://godbolt.org/z/GzEq54P8Y

Can anyone figure out why please?

Comment: How do you expect the compiler to inspect the members of a class before the class declaration is complete?

Comment: @fabian Doesn't that argument apply to both cases?

Comment: *"Doesn't that argument apply to both cases? "* No. Function (and constructor) bodies are compiled in a "complete-class context", like if they were defined after the class declaration (which they can be).

Comment: @SIMDoperator: "*And then use it as follows*" Why do that? If you want a virtual interface, just provide a virtual interface. Concepts should be checked at the site of use, not the site of the definition of the type(s) that fulfill them. Don't limit them by treating them as properties of a type.

Comment: cheers @NicolBolas. Yes the reason is static polymorphism. We could of course have `template<Shape T> void foo(T& t){ // ... }` at the site of use. But by having `Circle` satisfy `Shape` at definition time we warn the user **more** upfront. Please can you expand on why you think _concepts should be checked at the site of use, not the site of the definition of the type_?

Comment: @SIMDoperator: Because that's what the feature *is*. That's why there is special syntax for constraining the template which consumes types, but not syntax for constraining the *definition* of the type. Plus, concepts can represent relationships *between* types, which is not something that is known at definition time. Fundamentally, putting the constraint on the user side is is no different from declaring that a function takes a `BaseClass &`; you specify the interface at the point where that interface is *used*. You also specify it at definition time, but this is redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CRTP is amazing, but doesn't solve every problem.  CRTP is not the right tool here.

The test you need to do has to happen *after* the type is fully defined.

You have hacked it by putting a static assert in the constructor.

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/P1TezExEc) I simply put the static assert right after the class definition, when it is complete.

```
struct Circle
{
    float r;
    float area() const 
    {return 22*r*r/7;}
};
static_assert( Shape<Circle> );

struct Square
{
    double side;
    float area() const 
    {return side*side;}
};
static_assert( Shape<Square> );
```

now in a future version of C++, we expect to get reflection and eventually (maybe) metaclasses.

With metaclasses, you'd be able to do something like

```
class(Shape) Circle {
    float r;
    float area() const 
    {return 22*r*r/7;}
};
```

and the metaclass `Shape` would perform checks and manipulation of the struct.  This proposal [is in its early steps](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0707r4.pdf) and won't show up until after we have reflection (which was delayed from [c++23](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b23) by the pandemic).